# SaveAs PDF and open in Adobe Reader as new Tab

Tags: excel, vba, reader

I´m experiencing the following problem. To save an Excel Sheet as PDF, I´m using the following code.

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

This works perfectly fine the first time I´m executing the command. The File pops up as PDF format and is displayed in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. But when I execute it again, without closing the opened PDF file, I´m getting an error. As long as I always close the old PDF, there is no error. I´m pretty sure it is possible to open the next files in new tabs within Acrobat Reader without getting these errors in VBA. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: It is possible, but **it must have a different name**. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file having the same name, cannot be open in the same session of most of applications...

Please, use the next way, which gives different names and opens the same sheet in three consecutive tabs:

```
Sub expSheetAsPDFAndOpen()
   Dim strPDF As String, i As Long
   strPDF = ThisWorkbook.path & "\MyPDF"
   For i = 1 To 3
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
             Type:=xlTypePDF, _
             Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
             IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
             IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
             FileName:=strPDF & i & ".pdf", _
             OpenAfterPublish:=True
  Next i
End Sub
```

I suppose that you do not try exporting **the same sheet**. In such a case you may use the sheet names (being unique) to name the exported pdf.

Comment: It can in google chrome (the file gets overwritten and opens in a separate tab). Maybe it's an error in Acrobat Reader.

Comment: @Kostas K. Chrome is nicer, it allows opening the same page more times, like any browser... When try exporting in such a way (without supplying a name), VBA uses the workbook name and Acrobat Reader, Acrobat Pro etc. does not allow opening a file having the same full name. Should I understand that in your case Acrobat reader is able to open a document with the same name twice? Even manually? If so, my Acrobat Pro is unbearable... :) Anyhow, I will edit and writhe **almost** all applications.

Comment: Ah, no changes needed to your answer, it's perfectly valid. Chrome is an exception since it's a browser and doesn't lock the file for edit. :)

Comment: @Kostas It is a browser, but still an application... :)